# For each Loop in Java 8 : What is the best way to write the following code in Java 8

Tags: java, filtering

What is the best way to write the following code in Java 8 in terms of for loop and filtering.

```
boolean flag = true;
List<Feed> availableFeeds = data.getAvailableFeeds();
for (Feed feedElement : availableFeeds) {
    String type = feedElement.getType();
    if ("MatchState".equals(type)) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "best" is subjective

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you looking for how to implement this as a lambda?

Comment: looks good, but for proper encapsulation this should be in its own method. then instead of a break you will just return.

Answer (score 7):

```
boolean flag = data.getAvailableFeeds()
                   .stream()
                   .map(Feed::getType)
                   .noneMatch("MatchState"::equals)
```

The first line creates a stream out of the list. The second one maps each `Feed` to type by calling `getType`. The last one returns true if there is *no type* that equals the string "MatchState".

Comment: This is wrong. If any match the flag must be `false`

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Love `"MatchState"::equals`

Comment: This might be a noob question, but do we require null object handling inside map?

Comment: @Amriteya Yes if you do `type -> type.equals("MatchState")`. But here it is done the other way around.

Comment: @user7 I am assuming the same happens for `Feed::getType`? Does it have an inbuilt null pointer check?

Comment: I think the question was related to whether `map` could possibly call `Feed::getType` with `null` but the same issue would appear in the original `for`-loop code as well.

Comment: Yes this will throw a `NullPointerException` if there is a null feed in the list of feeds.

Comment: I am curious if `Stream` would pass any null objects to `map`? Or would it just removes all the null pointers and only passes non-null objects.

Comment: @Amriteya It doesn't remove anything. If list has nulls, then it would get passed as it is.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a something like `nonNullStream`. Specially for the objects that have not been encapsulated inside Optional.

Comment: @Amriteya `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` can be used, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @explv This looks better.

Comment: @BheshGurung That is not true. If breaks if it sees the string "MatchState"

Comment: @explv I don't mind having a filter to filter nulls, but it is not something that was in OP.

Comment: @explv The for-loop version would have thrown a NPE before. So by adding the check, you have changed the behaviour.

Comment: @user7 Now, I see how it works. +1. :)

Comment: @Michael apologies, I didn't notice OP didn't null check, I have reverted my edit, user7 can add it back if he wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You need filtering and a short break:

```
boolean flag = !availableFeeds.stream()
                              .map(Feed::getType)
                              .anyMatch(type -> "MatchState".equals(type));
```

or:

```
boolean flag = availableFeeds.stream()
                             .map(Feed::getType)
                             .allMatch(type -> !"MatchState".equals(type));
```

Comment: Also need to filter out nulls first.

Comment: No need because we use inverse equals: `"MatchState".equals(type)`

Comment: My bad. I see the original code is also ignoring the nulls.

Comment: I think you're overstressed on NPE. If code like you we have to check `data != null`, then `availableFeeds != null`. It's too verbose

Comment: I was just trying to make sure that your version is logically equivalent to the OP's code, but then I realized that I had misunderstood the OP's code.

Comment: Nevermind. Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is:

```
boolean flag = !data.getAvailableFeeds()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .anyMatch(feed -> feed.getType().equals("MatchState"));
```

This example constructs a `Stream<Feed>` from the `List<Feed>` returned by `getAvailableFeeds()`, and then calls `Stream<Feed>.anyMatch()` which accepts a `Predicate<Feed>` as it's parameter, in this case the predicate is a feed where the feed is not `null`, and the feed's type returned by `Feed.getType()` equals `"MatchState"`